# How to retrieve listview with image from mysql database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql

Below is my code, I tried a lot but images are not not showing up though everything else shows up. and in logcat I got this following error.

> E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@29043558: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>   I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@29043558

```java
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ImageView img2;     Bitmap bitmapOrg;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "xxxx://xxxxx.xx/xxxxx.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_Prix_Photo ="Photo";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray products = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        img2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Photo);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ViewProductActivity.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }





    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Entries: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String title = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                        String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                        String str1 = c.getString(TAG_Prix_Photo);
                        byte[] b = str1.getBytes();
                        byte[] ba2 = Base64.decode(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba2, 0, ba2.length);
                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                        map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                        map.put(TAG_Prix_Photo, String.valueOf(d));



                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            MainActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                            TAG_TITLE, TAG_PRICE, TAG_Prix_Photo},
                            new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.title, R.id.price,R.id.Photo});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can get image by calling `cursor.getBlog(column_index)` , then why are you getting it as string?

Comment: You should never store images into a DB, instead you should store only images locations (Paths). then you could use Picasso Library or Volley to retrieve them,

Comment: @Gatunox  i already stored only image paths in database,, and want to get all info like name price image etc in listview in android app, name price coming with this code but images are not coming .. its showing blank and getting error in catlog that   E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException  etc....

Comment: and where are the files located? The path is local or remote?

Comment: Remote path, files stored in folder of my web server..

Comment: basicaly its a free classified ad posting website for that i wnt to make android app so want to show ads with image in list view from php database in android app

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
Your image is in String so do this

```
String str1 = c.getString(TAG_Prix_Photo);
// byte[] b = str1.getBytes();
byte[] ba2 = Base64.decode(str1 ,Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba2, 0, ba2.length);
```

Comment: this is my avatar url in php file
$avatar = "http://www.xxxx.com/".$row['avatar'];

And this is how i getting that url through json array from that php file
$product["Photo"] = base64_encode($avatar);

So now what would be the problem

Comment: You're calling empty AsyncTask, change this; 
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

To; 
     new LoadAllProducts().execute(fileUrl);

Comment: not working.. still getting same error...

E/BitmapFactory﹕ Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@30a8aba3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@30a8aba3

Comment: Have you tried to load the url link in browser? What's the return value?

Comment: if i see with echo $avatar url then i got proper image in browser, 
if i see with $product["Photo"] url then i got something value like "aHR0cDovL3d3dy5pbmRpYXNmcmVlY2xhc3NpZmllZC5jb20vd3IvT05MSU5FLUZPUk0tRklMTElORy1QUk9KRUNUUy1BVkFJTEFCTEUtSmRmcW8uanBn"

Comment: OK. First of all you are returnning null from doInBackground which means onPostExecute is getting null. I will recommend y OK u to return JsonString to onPostExecute and process it there.

Comment: Additionally, in onPostExecute if the JsonString is null then start the new Activity instead of starting it in doInBackground

Comment: OK this will be slow because I'm using my phone. But will have a look

Comment: i am using laptop now,I am trying to Understand your code before processing. First where is the ImageView that's displaying product's Image?

Comment: in list_item.xml layout 
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Photo"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

Comment: The solution I can suggest is, Create CustomAdapter Class to for the ListView, Fetch the JSonString using AsyncTask as you already did. Pass that String to Adapter Class to Loop through the JsonArray then When it get to Product_Photo, Convert it to Bitmap as you did and set it to ImageView

Comment: Can you create Custom Adapter? if not Below is one of the Popular tutorial that can help you      http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: I tried all things but i cant retriew image in listview from php database with my above code... ...

Comment: Does the Url works and shows the image if you entered it directly into browser? If yes what info shows, pls post it.

Comment: In bytes or base64string?

Comment: I just want to complete my app for my classified site.. Everything done except upload image while posting ad and showing images with ads as i post above code.. Want to complete this app as soon as possible.. I hope i can cmplete it soon by solving this errors..

Comment: OK do you get any response without image included?

Comment: Without image its work perfect , showing all ads in listview.. Only images not show..

Comment: There is possibility that the image is too big to fetch till server connection time runs out.  Increase UrlConnection timeout and try and reduce the image. Additionally, while getting values from JSonObject make sure to.use the correct name I.e. Photo isn't same as photo

Comment: No. Everything is perfect.. And image is also not big.. Very small images like in kbs with only 200 width or height

Comment: Try to use "photo" Instead of "Photo" because if you getting wrong tag Name from JSonObject the return value will be null and that might explain the Error.

Comment: Let me try and will let u knw.. And let me knw if there is another easy way to show from php database with images in listview in android...

Comment: i tried with spell photo but still getting same error... dont whats wrong with it..

Comment: can u tell me how to use picasso with this list view code of mine???  i think that is the only solution for me... i tried with picasso but till not getting images so i m not master in android so may be i m doing some wrong so plz tell me how to use picasso with this code???

Comment: I have not use picasso library myself but check out this link, I hope it help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791871/how-to-correctly-implement-a-custom-listview-with-images-using-picasso-library

Comment: Ok let me check.. Thnx.. And So how u show images in listview with text from php database in android??

Comment: I don't use PHP, I use REST web service

Answer (score 0):

your php code must be become

```
base64_encode(base64_decode($row["TAG_Prix_Photo"]));
```